# Tensorflow weights not restored even after restoring from ckpt file

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am using the following code and the weights that are restored are random initializations and not the actual weights stored in ckpt file. Kindly help me in understanding where I went wrong.

```py
best_val_model = 'val_E1_A86.ckpt'
model_dir = './models/'

with tf.Session(config = config) as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print('Testing the model on 10000 Images!')
    ckpt_file = os.path.join(model_dir, best_val_model)
    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(ckpt_file)
    saver.restore(sess, ckpt_file)

    weights = {}
    for v in tf.trainable_variables():
        weights[v.name] = v.eval()
```

Actual model weights saved using `tf.train.Saver(sess,filename)` during training. While restoring, random weights are being restored.

Comment: You don't need to use `tf.global_variables_initializer()` when restoring. What was your motivation for introducing this line into your code?

Comment: It was throwing an error otherwise that variables need to be initialised before using them. This error comes from ```v.eval()``` part of the code.

Comment: then you can initialize only particular variables with `tf.initializers.variables`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to remove two lines `sess.run(tf.golbal_variables_initializer())` , `saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(ckpt_file)` and it worked fine. Final Code used:

```py
saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.trainable_variables())
with tf.Session(config = config) as sess:
   sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())
   print('Testing the model on 10000 Images!')
   ckpt_file = os.path.join(model_dir, best_val_model)
   saver.restore(sess, ckpt_file)
```